# cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable while sorting composite json

Tags: collections, gson

Problem statement: I am trying to sort a composite class using comparable and collections.sort but getting exception.

```
class BmetData implements Comparable<BmetData>{ Long mId;
String mName;
String mPath;
String frequency;
List<MValue> mValues;

public int compareTo(BmetData o) {
    return mId.compareTo(o.mId);
}}
```

SubClass -

```
class MValue implements Comparable<MValue> { Date startTimeInMillis;
Long current;
Long min;
Long max;
Long count;
Long sum;

Long value;

public int compareTo(MValue o) {
    return startTimeInMillis.compareTo(o.startTimeInMillis);
}}
```

I am getting response list of BmetData from API, parcing api response string using method -

```
public static <T> List<T> getJavaListFromJson(ApiResponseHolder apiResponse, Class<T> clazz) {

    if (apiResponse.getResponseCode() == 200) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        TypeToken<List<T>> token = new TypeToken<List<T>>() {
        };
        List<T> pojoList = gson.fromJson(apiResponse.getMessage(), token.getType());
        return pojoList;
    } else {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Which returns me `List<BmetData> list`
Now trying to sort it using Collections.sort(list) getting exception -

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1312)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1506)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1462)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:141)
    at Helper.ApiExecuterUsingToken.main(ApiExecuterUsingToken.java:70)`

Comment: `new TypeToken<List<T>>() { };` does not work. The parser still doesn’t know what `T` is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparable use Comparator for sorting.